# Can I make one dll depends on another dll in a different directory?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries

My program depends on Microsoft redistribute package, or to be more specific, depends on MSVCR100.dll

A recommanded approach is to install the redistribute package before my program running. However, my program is quite small(about 1MB), the vcredist.exe is about 5MB, it is a little too big for my installer.

So here is another way, according to license of Microsoft, we can install the dll into a subfolder(`\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.CRT\`) in my application folder. So my application directory is like:

```
MyAppFolder\a.exe
MyAppFolder\lib\a.dll
MyAppFolder\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.CRT\MSVCR100.dll
```

My question is, how do I make the a.dll find the MSVCR100.dll which located in another folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a function - [AddDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh310513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that can solve my problem.

Yes, I can link the CRT as a static library, but in my case there are several libraries that depend on it, which means every dll has a copy of MSVCR100.dll.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider linking CRT as static library, there will be no dependency on MSVCRxxx.dll,

but your EXE/DLL will be bigger.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984514.aspx

This solution is suitable if your project contains one EXE/DLL, but for bigger project you can create MSI package with MSVCRT merge module inside.